# Show that expression $f_n(t)=\int ^t_0 ne^{n(s-t)}f(s) ds$ such that $\lim_{n\to \infty} \|f_n-f\|_{L^p}=0$

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces, normed-spaces

Fix $p\in [1,+\infty)$ and let $f\in L_p[0,T]$. show that the expression
$$f_n(t)=\int ^t_0 ne^{n(s-t)}f(s) ds\quad t\in[0,T], n\in \mathbb{N}$$
defines a sequence of continuous functions such that $\lim_{n\to \infty} \|f_n-f\|_{L^p}=0$.

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \|f_n-f\|_{L^p}=\lim_{n\to \infty} \|\int ^t_0 ne^{n(s-t)}f(s) ds-f\|_{L^p}$$

I think if we write $f$ in terms of integral we can do processed but im not getting any idea. Any help please

Comment: Are you familiar with approximate identities and their properties?

Comment: @Jose27..SORRRY NO IDEA

Comment: It basically follow dominated convergence theorem. Try $$\int_{0}^{nt} e^{-r}f(t-\frac{r}{n})dr$$

Comment: are you sure that you have the correct formula for $f_n(t)$?